# Regex Solution with optional

Tags: c#, regex

Hello can you someone help me with an issue i want these 3 regex lines to be modified into a single regex line. 
Using C# regex

```
(?<reportName>\w+)(_[0-9])_v(?<reportVersion>\d+).tsd for === FBN001_v7.tsd
(?<reportName>\w+)_v(?<reportVersion>\d+).tsd for === FBN014B_2_v4.tsd
(?<reportName>\w+).tsd === for FBN002A.tsd
```

Comment: `for === FBN001_v7.tsd` Is this a part of Regex?

Comment: Use the ? which indicated 0 or 1 times.  You don't really need to parse anyting after the '.tsd'.  Try this : (?<reportName>\w+)(_[0-9])?(_v)?(?<reportVersion>\d+)?.tsd

Comment: for === FBN001_v7.tsd is comment not part of the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
(?<reportName>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:_[0-9]+)*(?:_v(?<reportVersion>\d+))?\.tsd
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3creportName%3e%5ba-zA-Z0-9%5d%2b)(%3f%3a_%5b0-9%5d%2b)*(%3f%3a_v(%3f%3creportVersion%3e%5cd%2b))%3f%5c.tsd&i=FBN001_v7.tsd%0d%0aFBN014B_2_v4.tsd%0d%0aFBN002A.tsd)

You need to escape the `.` since you want to match a literal `.`. If you do not escape it, `.` in regex matches any character (but a newline here).

[image]

Comment: thanks that works but it dosent capture reportVersion in a variable

Comment: Sorry, I was misled by the style of your question. I updated my answer, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
string txt = @"for === FBN001_v7.tsd
=== for FBN002A.tsd
for === FBN014B_2_v4.tsd";
string patten = @"(?<reportName>\w+?)((_[0-9])?_v(?<reportVersion>\d+))?\.tsd";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(txt, patten))
{
    Console.Write("reportName:" + match.Groups["reportName"].Value + "  ");
    if (match.Groups["reportVersion"].Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("reportVersion:" + match.Groups["reportVersion"].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------");
}
```

I think `for === FBN001_v7.tsd` is your regex demo